# Django maximum recursion depth exceeded in setattr

Tags: python, django

```
class MyModel(Model):
    is_valid = BooleanField(default=False)
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key == 'is_valid':
            print(self.is_valid)
        super(MyModel, self).__setattr__(key, value)
```

Why do I get maximum recursion error when accessing `self.is_valid`? 
From stack trace I see that `self.is_valid` triggers `instance.refresh_from_db(fields=[self.field_name])` which triggers `__setattr__`.

Stacktrace:

```
File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/ukr_tran/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 565, in from_db
    new = cls(*values)

File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/ukr_tran/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 481, in __init__
        setattr(self, field.attname, val)

File "/home/models/uk.py", line 647, in __setattr__
        print(key, self.is_valid)

File "/home/paul/.virtualenvs/ukr_tran/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query_utils.py", line 115, in __get__
        instance.refresh_from_db(fields=[self.field_name])
```

Comment: You need to show that stack trace. But haven't you answered your own question?

Comment: Question is why refresh_from_db is called?

Comment: As I say, you need to show the stack trace.

Comment: If the value of `is_valid` is not cached yet, it needs to load it from the DB, no?

Comment: Added stack trace.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to set value of is_valid depending on other conditions ignoring form data.

Comment: Then you should write a `clean` method, as detailed in [the docs on validating objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects), rather than messing around with `__setattr__`.

Comment: OK. Just wanted to know why setattr behaves is such a way.

Comment: Plese post full traceback also

Comment: @jpic The full traceback is going to be rather long and repetitive, so I guess there is little value in posting it.

Comment: I know what a recursion traceback looks like. The problem with the extract you posted is that it doesn't show the recursion. If you don't want to post it completely, at least post the beginning, the end, and twice whatever recurses a hundred times, so we can see the recursion.